# Why can my my C++ program correctly linked when I replace libstdc++ with libgcc

Tags: c++, c, name-mangling

Currently I read an article about **name mangling** on wikipeida([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)). In that article, I learn that the common `extern "C"` idiom is used to **protect those C code in C++ source file from being mangled**, which make those source code incompatible to be linked against the original C lib.

So I make the following reasoning:

If I write code like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and compile this with command `g++ test.cpp -o test`, then it will successfully compile with no doubt. We don't have to enclose `printf()` with `extern "C"`, even though `printf()` is a C function. **That's because**, **there is an another `printf()` in `libstdc++`, which is different from that in `libgcc`.**

So far, so good.

But I discover that that is not so true as I think.

I perform a few experiments:

I remove all the `libstdc++` under **/usr/lib** , which include

- /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libstdc++.a
- /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libstdc++.so
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19

and then I make a copy of `libgcc` and place it under the place where `libstdc++` has lived(otherwise the linker will complaint about **libstdc++ not found**)

**$sudo cp ./gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a ./gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libstdc++.a**

However, the code above compile, **without** the `extern "C"` !!!

Why is that? shouldn't it throw out a **Unresolved Reference** or something similar because the `printf()`,which have been mangled by the C++ compiler, incompatible with the `printf()` in li `libgcc` ?

---

any one tell me why my question get downvoted ?

---

Comment: How is `extern "C"` "famous"?

Comment: @Daniel Kamil Kozar I don't really know, but in that wiki page, it was called " common C++ idiom"

Comment: It is probably trying to link against the shared library `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19`. You need to add a flag to link statically. PS you did not need to move this lib there is a compiler option that removed the default libraries from the link command.

Comment: @LokiAstari Could you tell me which compiler option that is ?

Comment: Depends on the compiler: This is your friend `gcc -v -v -v --help | less`. There I found `-stdlib=<value>         C++ standard library to use` and `-fno-autolink           Disable generation of linker directives for automatic library linking`

Answer (score 3):

Your `extern "C"` is present, although it is hidden.

If you look in `stdio.h`, you will notice the line

```
 __BEGIN_DECLS
```

(line 29 on my system*) which in turn expands to

```
# define __BEGIN_DECLS       extern "C" {
```

(line 98 in `sys/cdefs.h` on my system) if you compile in C++ mode and to nothing otherwise. So the standard library header does the wrapping for you.

Removing your C++ standard libraries has no effect because those C functions live in the C standard library, and as all wrapping is done correctly, the linker can find and use them.

Now of course this is an implementation detail, in general, using `<stdio.h>` must work because the standard says so (currently, it's deprecated). How the compiler achieves that is not mandated.

---

*gcc6.1.1 packaged for Arch Linux

Answer (score 0):

g++ will notice that you are compiling something with a .c extension and treat it as a C source file.

[Make g++ compile C using gcc rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528300/make-g-compile-c-using-gcc-rules)

Instead of deleting libraries from your system, which has a good chance of going wrong at some point, use GCC flags to print library search paths and see what's going on. You may also be interested in nm (which prints the real symbol names in use), c++filt (which demangles names), and ldd (which prints the libraries linked with).

Comment: actually I save that file with a `.cpp` extention. Just a mispelling